# Openstack Not able to connect to using rest api

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have a local install on openstack on my virtual box. I am trying to use the lib cloud api to connnect and get a list of images,flavours etc.

Below is the code that I am trying to execute

```
    from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

# Authentication information so you can authenticate to DreamCompute
# copy the details from the OpenStack RC file
# https://dashboard.dreamcompute.com/project/access_and_security/api_access/openrc/

auth_username = 'admin'
auth_password = 'f882e2f4eaad434c'
TENANT_NAME = 'admin'
project_name = 'admin'
auth_url = 'http://192.168.56.101:5000/v3/tokens'
region_name = 'RegionOne'

provider = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
conn = provider(auth_username,
                auth_password,
                ex_force_auth_url=auth_url,
                ex_force_auth_version='2.0_password',
                ex_tenant_name=project_name,
                ex_force_service_type='compute',
                ex_force_service_name='compute',
                ex_force_base_url='http://192.168.56.101:8774/v2.1/29a8949bc3a04bfead0654be8e552017')


# Get the image that we want to use by its id
# NOTE: the image_id may change. See the documentation to find
# all the images available to your user
image_id = '4525d442-e9f4-4d19-889f-49ab03be93df'  
image = conn.get_image(image_id)

# Get the flavor that we want to use by its id
flavor_id = '100'
flavor = conn.ex_get_size(flavor_id)

# Create the node with the name “PracticeInstance”
# and the size and image we chose above
instance = conn.create_node(name='PracticeInstance', image=image, size=flavor)
```

When I run the above code I am getting below error:

```
C:\Python dev\website\music\openstack>python openstack.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openstack.py", line 30, in <module>
    image = conn.get_image(image_id)
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\compute\drivers\openstack.py", line 2028, in get_image
    '/images/%s' % (image_id,)).object['image'])
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack.py", line 223, in request
    raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\base.py", line 536, in request
    action = self.morph_action_hook(action)
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack.py", line 290, in morph_action_hook
    self._populate_hosts_and_request_paths()
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack.py", line 324, in _populate_hosts_and_request_paths
    osa = osa.authenticate(**kwargs)  # may throw InvalidCreds
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack_identity.py", line 855, in authenticate
    return self._authenticate_2_0_with_password()
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack_identity.py", line 880, in _authenticate_2_0_with_password
    return self._authenticate_2_0_with_body(reqbody)
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\openstack_identity.py", line 885, in _authenticate_2_0_with_body
    method='POST')
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\base.py", line 637, in request
    response = responseCls(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\C5265680\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\libcloud\common\base.py", line 157, in __init__
    message=self.parse_error())
libcloud.common.exceptions.BaseHTTPError: {"error": {"message": "The resource could not be found.", "code": 404, "title": "Not Found"}}
```

I have checked the logs in my server at /var/log/keystone and it does not give any error so I am guessing that I am able to login.

Also there are many examples which show that after the above steps I should be able to get list of images/flavors/servers.

Not sure why i am not able to connect. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should modify the `auth_url` and provider arguments.
As following argument set is worked at my environment.

```
auth_username = 'admin'
auth_password = 'f882e2f4eaad434c'
TENANT_NAME = 'admin'
project_name = 'admin'
auth_url = 'http://192.168.56.101:5000'
region_name = 'RegionOne'

provider = get_driver(Provider.OPENSTACK)
conn = provider(auth_username,
                auth_password,
                ex_force_auth_url=auth_url,
                ex_force_auth_version='2.0_password',
                ex_tenant_name=project_name)
```

**Updated 2017.11.16**

@user8040338 Your error message is the first clue, 
`The resource could not be found.` and status `code 404`, the most cause of its message and status code is wrong rest api url format.

Firstly, you need to check [keystone v2.0 rest api format](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v2/). 
At the same time, you check again [Libcloud reference](http://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/v0.14.0/compute/drivers/openstack.html).
For instance, the argument `ex_force_auth_version` had been specified the api version `2.0_password` (v2), but `auth_url` variable formed the url including  the version resource `/v3`, it was wrong version and usage of API with the libcloud API argument you specified. `auth_url` should be a base URL from API usage.

The similar processes about each argument of API should be conducted repeatedly until solving issues.

Comment: I have tried various combinations.Below is the out put of your suggestion.I had tried it earlier as well.

Comment: Thanks that worked. How did you know the arguments and the auth url needs to be modifed.Any reference link that you could guide me to would be very helpful.

Comment: @user8040338 The additional comment is too long to write as comment, so i have modified the question including the references.